# Terminal can’t use 'mv', because 'permission denied' (Linux Mint/Debian)

Tags: linux, permissions, samba

I want to move a file using mv; this is the command:

```
mv /etc/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf.bak
```

But it returns:

```
mv: cannot move "/etc/samba/smb.conf" to "/etc/samba/smb.conf.bak": permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to install Samba server on my laptop for a local Windows file sharing server. I am a new user to Linux, and this PC is a secondary laptop. My primary is a Windows 10 laptop.

Comment: It is not the terminal, it is your system. The same command started in a program (e.g. with [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)... or `fork` + `execve`) would fail likewise. The [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.htmll) system call, used in any of your programs, would also fail. So moving that file in a desktop GUI would also fail

Answer (score 8):

You’re trying to rename a file in a system directory (`/etc/samba`),
presumably using your user account, and presumably your account
doesn’t have permission to make changes in that directory. 
Try running

```
sudo mv /etc/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf.bak
```

Comment: `root@DESKTOP-QLRRVVV:~/home# sudo mv vlc-android vlc-android-3.3.3
mv: cannot move 'vlc-android' to 'vlc-android-3.3.3': Permission denied`